# Symfony handle form request logic

Tags: symfony

Sorry if this question is too messy, but is there a common way to handle form request in Symfony ? (I use SF 4).

For now, I have the logic in my controller :

```
$formBooking = $this->createForm(BookingType::class);

    $formBooking->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formBooking->isSubmitted() && $formBooking->isValid()) {
        // perform actions ...
```

I have several forms on the same page, so my controller gets bigger and bigger.

I wanted to creation a new folder like **Action** and put the logical here.

And do in my controller :

```
 $formBooking = $this->createForm(BookingType::class);

 // $bookingAction = new App\Action\BookingAction
 $bookingAction->handleRequest($formBooking, $request);
```

I just want to know if there any "official" way for this ?

Comment: You have two way to split your code, first create many controller base on your business logic. second is to move to service your business logic to keep top level layer your Controller.

Comment: Yes I will move to Action, I don't want to mix with services since Action are only for forms handle. It's more logical for me to keep Controllers as top level layer.

Comment: Think carefully about the first comment.  Limiting yourself to one action per controller will solve the issue of your controllers growing out of control.  And eliminate the rather awkward BookingAction separation that you propose.

Comment: For my information, why this separation is awkward ? SymfonyDoc say it's better to hande form request in the same method / controller. Is it better to create a new controller and set the action of the form to this controller ? Thanks.

Comment: Your first code is the "standard" way to handle forms.  That section you labeled "// perform actions" is what you might consider moving to another service.  Assuming it is more complex then just persisting your booking object and redirecting.  The service should have no knowledge of the form or the request.  But again, if your main goal is to reduce controller code then one action per controller is an easy starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract "BaseController", and inherit your other controller. I don't think this is an "official" way, but it seems proper.

In my example, I have set my entity manager, my form factory and my routing as services. Also, it's called BaseManager, as all my logic are in manager file, while my controller doesn't have code (kind of just calling my manager, except for specific cases)

To do so, simply reference your service, and let your controller be the master, but a clean and simple one.

```
## Controller##
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Form\CategoryType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
/**
 * @Route("/admin/category")
 */
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/", name="category_index")
     * @return array
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $categories = $this->get('app.category.manager')->find();
        return array('categories' => $categories);
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/", name="category_menu")
     * @return array
     */
    public function menuAction()
    {
        $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAllOrdered("ASC");
        return array('categories' => $categories);
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/icones/glyficones", name="category_icones_glyficones")
     * @return array
     */
    public function fontawesomeAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/icones/fontawesome", name="category_icones_fontawesome")
     * @return array
     */
    public function glyficoneAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/new", name="category_create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->get('app.category.manager')->save($request);
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="category_edit")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return array
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return $this->get('app.category.manager')->edit($request, $id);
    }
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="category_delete")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return array
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return $this->get('app.category.manager')->delete($request, $id);
    }
}
```

### Base Manager

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Manager;
use AppBundle\Form\CategoryType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
abstract class BaseManager
{
    protected $em;
    protected $formFactory;
    protected $router;
    /**
     * CategoryManager constructor.
     * @param $em
     * @param $formFactory
     * @param Router $router
     */
    public function __construct($em, $formFactory, Router $router)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    /**
     * @param $entity
     */
    protected function persistAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    /**
     * @param $entity
     */
    protected function removeAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->remove($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Form $form
     * @param $entity
     * @param $path
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function handleBaseForm(Request $request, Form $form, $entity, $path)
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->persistAndFlush($entity);
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($path));
        }
        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
    /**
     * @param $route
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function redirect($route)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($route));
    }
}
```

And here an example, a simple crud froma "Category" entity.

### Specific Entity Manager

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Manager;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Form\CategoryType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
/**
 * Class CategoryManager
 * @package AppBundle\Manager
 */
class CategoryManager extends BaseManager
{
    /**
     * CategoryManager constructor.
     * @param $em
     * @param $formFactory
     * @param Router $router
     */
    public function __construct($em, $formFactory, Router $router)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $formFactory, $router);
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function find()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        return $this->handleForm($request, $category);
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $category = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($id);
        return $this->handleForm($request, $category);
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $category = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($id);
        $this->persistAndFlush($category);
        return $this->redirect('category_index');
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Category $category
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handleForm(Request $request, $category)
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(CategoryType::class, $category);
        return $this->handleBaseForm($request, $form, $category, "category_index");
    }
}
```

Just if needed, here are my services.yaml file

```
services:
  app.category.manager:
    class: AppBundle\Manager\CategoryManager
    arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@form.factory', '@router' ]

  fos_user.doctrine_registry:
      alias: doctrine
```

Hope it may help solving your issue, and get a cleaner code. Please, note that this is a personnal solution, and there are probably better solutions. But this one is a working one, which seems, for me, cleaner than just let the controller have all the logic